# Find if lines on one file appear as words in the lines of another file in Python

Tags: python

I have two text files. File one has one word in each line and has about 10Klines.  My second file which is the corpus file has about 69k lines and has sentences in it. Each line is an individual sentence

File 1 looks like this

[image: file1image].

And File 2 looks like this

[image: file2image]

In file 1 each line is considered as a single word.
I need to find if words from file 1 appear within the sentences of file 2 as words and if they do how many of them appear in the corpus file. I tried the following code but it returns empty lists. Any clue as to why empty lists are returned?

```
f=open('Corpus_WX.txt',encoding='utf-8')
for count in range(0,68630):
    g=f.readline()
    words=g.split()
    x=open("Processed_data_edit.txt")
    h=x.readline()
    word=h.split()
    x.close()
    z=list(set(words).intersection(word))
    with open("New_Matches.txt", 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            file.write(str(z))
            file.write("\n")
            file.close()
    count=count+1
```

My logic was to find the common elements here and then compare with file 1 again to get a count of the matches. Is there a better way to get both these steps done simultaneously?

Comment: Try to use dictionary ..

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: Make File 1 a dictionary?

Comment: To make it as counter you can use Dictionary..

Comment: Please include your input files as _formatted text_, not screenshots. This way, we can copy them onto our computers and show you the output that our code gives without having to type out the files ourselves. You can format the text as a code-block, by adding three backticks ( ` ) on the lines before and after your file contents. [Formatting help](/help/formatting)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Will keep this in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to find out how many words in `file2` occur in `file1`, you just need to read in both files and find the size of the intersection of the sets containing the words in both files.

```
with open("file1.txt") as f:
    file1_words = f.readlines()

with open("file2.txt") as f:
    file2_words = f.read().split() # Read everything and split by whitespace

file1_words = set(file1_words)
file2_words = set(file2_words)

common_words = file1_words.intersection(file2_words)
print(f"File1 and File2 have {len(common_words)} words in common")
```

---

If you want to *count* the occurrences of each word from `file1` in `file2`, you'll need to write some more code.

First, read the second file and count the occurrences of each word. You could use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for this, but it's pretty easy to write your own code if you're learning:

```
with open("file2.txt") as f:
    file2_words = f.read().split() # Read everything, then split by whitespace

file2_wordcount = dict() # Empty dictionary

for word in file2_words:
    old_count = file2_wordcount.get(word, 0) # Get the count from the dict. Or 0 if it doesn't exist
    file2_wordcount[word] = old_count + 1 # Set the new count
```

At the end of this block, we have a dictionary `file2_wordcount` which maps each word to its count in the second file. Next, we need to read the words from the first file and find out how many times they occur in the other file.

```
# Now, read the lines from file 1
with open("file1.txt") as f:
    file1_words = f.readlines() # Since you have one word per line.

# Convert it into a set to remove duplicates
file1_words = set(file1_words)

for word in file1_words:
    count = file2_wordcount.get(word, 0) # Get the count from the dict. Or 0 if it doesn't exist
    print(word, count) # Print them both
```

Or, to get the total count, use the `sum()` function:

```
total_common_count = sum(file2_wordcount.get(word, 0) for word in file1_words)
```